# Error with grub2-install on Amazon Linux 2023 after Migrating to LVM with EFI System

Tags: grub2, uefi, amazon

I set up an Amazon Linux 2023 EC2 and migrated the disk over to a new one to use LVM, (I didnt put the BIOS and `/boot/efi` on LVM.) I believe my system is using EFI, as indicated by the contents in `/sys/firmware/efi/`, but I'm facing an error with `grub2-install`.

Here's the sequence of commands I ran:

```bash
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
dracut -f -H --regenerate-all
grub2-install --recheck /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

However `grub2-install` fails with the following error:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
done
grub2-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Many distributions have the BIOS version of GRUB and the UEFI version of GRUB as separate packages. The error message suggests the package that brings the UEFI version of GRUB modules is not installed on your system.

According to [Amazon Linux 2023 package list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-AL2023.3.html), it seems you might need to install at least the `grub2-efi-x64-modules` package. You might be missing other `grub2-efi-x64-*` packages too.

Unfortunately the package listing does not include package descriptions nor dependencies, so I cannot say for sure. If someone with actual access to UEFI-bootable AL2023 reads this, feel free to edit this answer or write your own.